# converting functions of %matplotlib notebook into Python script

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to convert several python notebook file into python scripts so that I can create a python package...
The problem I'm having now is that in python notebook, there's

```
%matplotlib notebook
```

magic button that makes user can click on a plot and receive the coordinate of the plot he/she just clicked on. The way to realize it is below:

```
f = urllib.urlopen(url_link)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(3,3))
coords = coordinates(my_coord)[1]
image = plt.imread(f)
plt.imshow(image)

collector = {'x':0,'y':0}
def onclick(event):
    collector['x'] = event.x
    collector['y'] = event.y

cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event',onclick)
print(collector)
```

Now I would like to make the same function in python script. but in script

```
%matplotlib notebook
```

is not working. Is there any alternative way that allows my python script do the same thing: showing plot and user can click on and return coordinate user clicked?

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In principle there is no need for such event handling, since this is automatically available in the matplotlib plotting window.

The following script

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image = plt.imread("image.jpg")

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4,3))
ax.imshow(image)

plt.show()
```

produces this window

[image]

which shows the coordinates of the current mouse position inside the lower status bar.

But of course the functionality can be extended as in the question by using the same event handling mechanism

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image = plt.imread("image.jpg")

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4,3))
ax.imshow(image)

collector = {'x':0,'y':0}
def onclick(event):
    collector['x'] = event.x
    collector['y'] = event.y
    print(collector)

cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event',onclick)

plt.show()
```

Note that this will print the figure coordinate, not the data coordinate. Since the figure coordinate is pretty useless in most cases, it would be better to use the data coordinates, like this.

```
collector['x'] = event.xdata
collector['y'] = event.ydata
```

Also see the [event handling article](http://matplotlib.org/users/event_handling.html) on the matplotlib page.

Comment: cool! but there's still one more problem... the return value is always in integer form but i want it as floating point for later use.. any solution allows me to do that?

Comment: What do you mean by `return` value? There is no return here. Of course you can cast the values to `float` like `collector['x'] = float(event.xdata)` if that is what you mean.

Comment: i meant whether it can print out the coordinate of the point i clicked more precisely. If i clicked on x:503.449 y:521.459, i will get x-503 and y=521 instead of original value. is there any way i can avoid this approximation?

Comment: When I click on the image, it prints `{'y': 267.66354838709674, 'x': 71.209677419354819}`. I'm using matplotlib 2.0, this may have been different in previous versions.

Comment: okay thx! I will try to give a shot on changing a version of matplotlib..

Comment: I just checked my matplotlib version. It's 2.0.0. But it only returns me integers. Any idea? Totally trapped into this problem

Comment: Can you reformulate and summarize the problem again? Which code is producing what? Maybe add a screenshot?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42794479/converting-matplotlibs-event-coordinates-into-floating-numbers

Comment: check out this page. I formulated the question into a more understandable way.