# converting matplotlib's event coordinates into floating numbers

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image = plt.imread("image.png")

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4,3))
ax.imshow(image)

collector = {'x':0,'y':0}
def onclick(event):
    collector['x'] = event.x
    collector['y'] = event.y
    print(collector)

cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event',onclick)

plt.show()
```

Basically, what I want is:
Every time print(collector) gives back exact values of point I clicked. e.g.     {'y': 267.66354838709674, 'x': 71.209677419354819}   instead of {'y': 268, 'x': 71} 
I am using matplotlib 2.0.0 
Got any ideas? Thx!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [converting functions of %matplotlib notebook into Python script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42541999/converting-functions-of-matplotlib-notebook-into-python-script)

Comment: In this question I already pointed to the solution, which is, I quote: "it would be better to use the data coordinates, like this `collector['x'] = event.xdata`."